# Grails + GORM: Is there an equivalent to hibernate's @Generated?

Tags: hibernate, grails, entity, grails-orm

I'm currently working on a grails project, where I have to map a legacy database with GORM. Some of the database columns are auto-generated by triggers.

My problem is now that after I save an entity, the state of the columns that were auto-generated is not reflected in the entity.

I know that I could do `entity.refresh()` to force a reload of the whole entity from the database. But I don't think this is a viable solution, as such scenarios should be handled transparently. And I don't want to explicitly refresh entities after every save.

I do know that in hibernate there exists a `@Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)` annotation that does exactly what I want to do.

**Is there an equivalent way to do this with GORM?**

Comment: Probably no, i think You should create a new issue in grails data mapping project for this feature request

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that GORM supports this natively (but would be interested if another answer can show a way!) but the documentation here: http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/refresh.html suggests that refresh is indeed the correct approach.

You can combine that with supported events (afterInsert and afterUpdate should work for you) to refresh your object.  That isn't completely transparent, but is at least fully contained within your domain object.

```
// I didn't actually test this but it should work like this, or similar.  
//Put the method in your domain object itself and it will be called automatically.

def afterInsert(){
    this.refresh()
}
```